# how to hide details in excel row to only show the main information and to be able to show it only on click

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel, could anyone help?

My data:

```
id        | product | single cost | sum of costs
------------------------------------------------
project1  | a       | 1           | 3
------------------------------------------------
          | b       | 2           |
------------------------------------------------
project2  | a       | 1           | 12
------------------------------------------------
          | b       | 2           |
------------------------------------------------
          | c       | 3           |
```

How to hide the column "single cost"... but show it when clicking "sum of costs"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if you want to hide the row/column entirely or if you want to hide the row/column but allow the user to unhide it easily by clicking. Hiding a row or column in Excel is straightforward -- highlight the row(s)/column(s) you would like to hide, then click on "Format" in the cells portion of the "Home" tab and go to "Hide & Unhide."

If you want the rows or column to be hidden but easily expanded open, you can use Excel's "Group" functionality. Highlight the row(s)/column(s) you would like to hide, then go to the "Data" tab. In the "Outline" area, select "Group." This will add a plus/minus sign either above the column or beside the row -- clicking the minus will hide the rows/columns, clicking the plus when they're hidden will make them visible again.

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Grouping is a good idea, but i have two problems in this case:  1. i want the first row to appear on case of grouping and then to be able to click on him to see the details
2. i want to do the same process for an entire databasse, so i cant do it manuelly.